# How can I expose camel mbean in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, jmx

I am migrating the application from 2.23.2 to 3.1.0 version.

The application works fine having 2 routes.

But a mbean is not exposed in jconsole.

There are basic mbeans in jconsole.

- JMImplementation

- com.sun.management

- com.zaxxer.hikari

- connector

- java.lang

- java.nio

- java.util.logging

- javax.management.remote.rmi

- org.apache.logging.log4j2

- org.springframework.boot

How can I handle this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a dependency to your project for `camel-management`. For example:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-management</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

There's a note about this in the Camel 3.x upgrade guide:

https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/camel-3x-upgrade-guide.html#_spring_boot_jmx